# How to remove jQuery element added by .append()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

**General info**
I'm working on a intranet based administration system for a distribution centre.
**Situation**
Basicly I have a contenteditable table with all user data. Except for the passwords of course. You could compare it with a webbased Excel sheet. Using a jQuery UI dialog, I'm popping op a form that allows the admin (company manager) of the system to change the employees passwords if clicked on a button.
To make sure the password change will be applied to the correct user, I'm passing along the used id to my function that pops up the dialog. Using `.append()` I'm adding this id to the form. Up to this point everything works perfectly fine.
**Problem**
If the password change is cancelled, the id must be removed from the form again. Otherwise you end up appending more and more ids to the form on each user clicked. The same goes for when the password change is succeeded. I've tried doing this with jQuery `.remove()`, but it doesn't seem to work, even though I can't find any issue with the code.
**Code**

```
function changePass(id){
    var addID = $("<input>")
        .attr("type", "text")
        .attr("id", "userid")
        .attr("name", "userid").val(id);
    $('#passChangeForm').append($(addID));
    $("#changePass").dialog({
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        title: "Change password",
        buttons: [
            {
                text: "Cancel",
                click: function() {
                    $("#passChangeForm").remove("#userid");
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
            {
                text: "Ok",
                click: function() {
                    $("#passChangeForm").submit();
                }
            }
        ]
    });
}

$("#passChangeForm").on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var password = document.getElementById("chPass1").value;
    var password2 = document.getElementById("chPass2").value;
    var userid = document.getElementById("userid").value;
    $.ajax({
        url: "system/changepass.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:'pass1='+password+'&pass2='+password2+'&id='+userid,
        success: function(text){
            alert(text);
            $("#passChangeForm").remove("#userid");
            $("#changePass").dialog("close");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Where you are appending the id, could you not just change it so you will append a whole form and then if the user cancels it will remove the whole form?

Comment: @Canvas I'm sure that would be possible. But if it doesn't remove a single input element, why would it remove a form element? I appreciate your suggestion, but right now it sounds like simply moving the problem to another element.

Comment: Do you find the element by id? E.g. does `console.log($("#userid").get(0))` yield any result?

Comment: @pingul Yes it returned `<input type="text" id="userid" name="userid">` as expected.

Comment: $("#userid").remove()  instead of $("#passChangeForm").remove("#userid");

Comment: @ilanberci Yes I figured it out just a few secs before your comment, haha. It works perfect now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use this :

```
$( "#userid" ).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
$("#passChangeForm").remove("#userid");
```

to

```
$("#userid").remove();
```